# Is there a way of adding username and password into the bzr checkout command?

Tags: bazaar

I'm trying to automate an install process using bash, the following Bazaar command are part of this:

`bzr export /home/path bzr+https://adress`

`bzr checkout bzr+https://address/ /home/path`

After running these commands manually I'm prompted for username and password.
Is there any way of adding username and password directly into the commands in order to avoid the prompting?

Checked the Bazaar documentation, but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard format for HTTP URLs can be used to pass a username/password combination:

```
 $ bzr checkout bzr+https://username:password@host/path /local/path
```

Another option would be to add your credentials to `~/.config/bazaar/authentication.conf`. See this page for details: http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/beta/en/user-reference/authentication-help.html